# How do I create a new column that is based on multiple values in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table that has three columns. Name, Status & ID
[image: Here's the sample table]

Now I've got to make a row called final status that has a status based on all the orders of a person.

So for John since both his orders are delivered the final status would be complete.

For David since the status on his two orders are submitted and created his final status would be IN Progress. Hope that makes sense.

I've already thought about trying to split the status into different columns and using a case statement afterwords, but I've got no idea how to do all that in a single query.

Would really appreciate some help here!

Another clarification that I'd like to add is that different combinations of the status would provide different final statuses:

1. When all orders for a customer are delivered then the status is COMPLETE
2. So if the customer has orders that are not DELIVERED and some that are DELIVERED, the status would be IN PROGRESS
3. If all of the customers orders are submitted then its status would be awaiting progress
4. Otherwise the final status would be awaiting submission

Comment: You are using some nonstandard sql here which is OK if you stick with MySQL.  The sum(status='DELIVERED') statement depends on TRUE=1 and FALSE=0 which other db systems do not perform or permit.

Comment: Yea you're right, I had to build the solution in a MySQL environment. Had to look it up as well, definitely seemed weird at first to me but could not for the life of me figure any other way of solving the problem since I'm not too familiar with MySQL and I'm fairly new to SQL on top of that.

Comment: Add a solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to retrieve data in the way you've described, you may try below -

```
Select distinct customer_name, 
CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT status FROM cust_order_status os1 
             WHERE os1.order_id = os.order_id 
             and upper(os1.status) <> 'DELIVERED')
       THEN 'In Progress' 
       ELSE 'Complete'
  END AS FinalOrderStatus  
from cust_order_status os;
```

Updated query after your edits -

```
Select distinct customer_name, 
CASE 
       WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT status FROM cust_order_status os1 
             WHERE os1.order_id = os.order_id 
             and upper(os1.status) <> 'DELIVERED')
       THEN 'Complete' 
       ELSE 
            CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT status FROM cust_order_status os1 
             WHERE os1.order_id = os.order_id 
             and upper(os1.status) = 'DELIVERED')
             THEN 'In Progress'
            ELSE
            CASE 
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT status FROM cust_order_status os1 
             WHERE os1.order_id = os.order_id 
             and upper(os1.status) <> 'SUBMITTED')
             THEN 'Awaiting Progress'
            ELSE 'Awaiting Submission'
            END
       END
  END AS FinalOrderStatus  
from cust_order_status os;
```

Comment: Hi Appreciate the reply, I forgot to  mention another part of my question which I've now added in the Edit above.
Could you please tell me how you'd go about adding those conditions to your query?

Comment: Hello Ahn, I have updated the query after your updated requirement. Please accept this as answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarifications this is slightly more complex.  You are implying that the statuses themselves are part of a sequence, so we'll need to map them to their sequential point in the sequence, aggregate across the customer each distinct status, and then remap the combined result to your combined status.

```
Select Customer_name,
       Case When all_statuses='3' Then 'Complete'
            When all_statuses like '3%' Then 'In Progress'
            When all_statuses like '2%' Then 'Awaiting Progress'
            Else 'Awaiting Submission' End as final_status
From (
      Select Customer_name, 
             Group_Concat(Distinct Case when status='CREATED' Then '1'
                                       When status='SUBMITTED' Then '2'
                                       When status='DELIVERED' Then '3' End
                          Order by Case when status='CREATED' Then '1'
                                      When status='SUBMITTED' Then '2'
                                       When status='DELIVERED' Then '3' End desc
                          Separator '') as all_statuses
      From Mytable
      Group by Customer_name
     )
```

If Group_Concat won't let you embed the Case When mapping then you'll have to do the case mapping in one Select, the group_concat in a second, and the remapping in a third.